# Tag-Synonym : "Pneumatology" and "Holy-Spirit" request

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Tag-Synonym : [pneumatology](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pneumatology) and [holy-spirit](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holy-spirit) request.

Might have to be merged, actually.

> Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag.

Answer (score 2):

I merged these two into the technical term and left a synonym behind from the more common parlance term.